# ionic 2: how to dismiss loader after data is ready?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 app, I have i have component that GET to fetch data.
i want to maker loader and dismiss it after data is ready.
i tried to look on other posts around the stack overflow but my issue is different.
i did something but the loader is forever and its not helps me.

It looks like following:

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController,LoadingController,AlertController,ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Facebook } from 'ionic-native';

//import pages
import {LoginPage} from "../../pages/login/login";
import {User} from '../../models/user'
import { Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
//import provider
import { ProfileData } from '../../providers/profile-data';
import { NotesData } from '../../providers/notes-data';

import firebase from 'firebase'
import {AddNote} from "../add-note/add-note";

/*
Generated class for the NotesList page.

See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
selector: 'page-notes-list',
templateUrl: 'notes-list.html'
})
export class NotesList {

//facebook user
userProfile: any = null;
uid: any = null;
fireUid:any=null;
name:string=null;
photo: any =null;
user:User=null;
photos:any=null;
currentUser:any=null;
photonew:any=null;
//notes list

notes:any=null;
data:any;
pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public profileData:ProfileData,private viewCtrl: ViewController,public notesData:NotesData,private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,private alertCtrl: AlertController,public storage:Storage) {
this.data={};
this.data.title="";
this.data.desc="";

}

ionViewDidLoad() {
```

//if i do that the loader is forever
/*
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      dismissOnPageChange: true,
    });

```
loader.present();
```

*/
    // here i want the loader to be until the data is ready.
    this.getNotesList(); //this functions not returns data so i can't do this.getNotesList().then(()=>

```
}

getNotesList(){
console.log("get event");
var that=this;
this.notesData.getNotesLIst().on('value', snapshot => {
let notesList= [];
snapshot.forEach( snap => {
console.log("id note"+snap.val().id);
notesList.push({
id: snap.val().id,
title: snap.val().title,
desc: snap.val().desc,
color:snap.val().color,
photo:snap.val().photo,
});
});
that.notes = notesList;

});
}
addNote(){
this.navCtrl.push(AddNote);
}

logOutFacebook(){
Facebook.logout().then((response)=>
{
this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
alert(JSON.stringify(response));
},(error)=>{
alert(error);
})
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should show how do you implement your loading page. Is it a splash screen with cordorva? Or just as div displaying some image? 
If it is a splash screen, you can add this code in your component after you get data, (it is from starter template, you can see the detail by creating a new project with `ionic start`):

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
  Splashscreen.hide();
});
```

And, if you use a div in your index page, it is similar, you can just get that element and remove it, with pure js.

Answer (score 0):

okay it succeed to do that
this is my answer

```
    ionViewDidLoad() {

    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({});
    loader.present();
    this.getNotesList().then((x) => {
      if (x) loader.dismiss();
    });




  }

  getNotesList(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      var that=this;
      this.notesData.getNotesLIst().on('value', snapshot => {
        let notesList= [];
        snapshot.forEach( snap => {
          console.log("id note"+snap.val().id);
          notesList.push({
            id: snap.val().id,
            title: snap.val().title,
            desc: snap.val().desc,
            color:snap.val().color,
            photo:snap.val().photo,
          });
        });
        that.notes = notesList;
        resolve(true);
      });
    })
  }
```